# Save a place in Street View

Tags: google-maps, street-view

Is it possible to save a place while in Street View mode?

For example with this [Google Maps link](https://www.google.com/maps/@51.5251779,-0.0873637,3a,75y,114.34h,81.23t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1s-3FSZN6A4K7GAbyMkqlX7g!2e0!7i13312!8i6656) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9xkq.jpg))

If I click the pin icon in the top left corner, it takes me to a screen where there's a Save button, but I can't go back to Street View from there, so I'm not sure it refers to the same place I was seeing in Street View. Is there a way to save the exact view I'm seeing directly from Street View, so I can go back there from the app, or is saving the URL the only way?